# update listview from fragment within viewpager from main activity

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

**COMPLETELY EDITED**

Ok I will try to be more specific.

I'm developing a small app drawer. Therefore I need a way to let the user choose categories.
This is the main point of the question. If there is another better way than my approach please let me know.

So my try to implement this was to load all apps to an array list and save this to a service to make it available throuout the app. The loading of the apps is done by an asynctask.

MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    packageManager = getPackageManager();

    if ((AppDrawerService.getApps()) == null) {
        apps = new ArrayList<ApplistItem>();
        loadAppsToService();

    } else {

        //if Service already holds the data
        manageViews();
    }
}

private void loadAppsToService() {

    LoadApplications loadApps;
    loadApps = new LoadApplications(this);
    loadApps.setOnLoadApplicationsFinishedListener(this);
    loadApps.execute();
}

private void manageViews() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    myViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    myViewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, this));
}

@Override
public void OnLoadApplicationsComplete(ArrayList<ApplistItem> apps) {
    manageViews();
}
```

LoadApplications:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
    AppDrawerService.setApps(apps);
    listener.OnLoadApplicationsComplete(apps);
    super.onPostExecute(o);
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment category = null;

    category = new AppListFragment()

    return category;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    pages = 5;
    return pages;
}
```

AppListFragment:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    if ((AppDrawerService.getApps()) == null) {
        apps = new ArrayList<ApplistItem>();
    } else {
        apps = AppDrawerService.getApps();
    }

    v = getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    myApplist = (ListView) v;
    applistAdapter = new ApplistAdapter(context, 0, apps);
    myApplist.setAdapter(applistAdapter);
    myApplist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

The problem which I have with this code is, that it alway populates only one Fragment with the applist. On first start the first fragment is populated with the apps but if you swipe two fragments to right and then one back to left, this fragment (the second) is populated. The impression which I have is that the

```
return new ApplistFragment();
```

from the ViewPager does actually not create an independent instance of the fragment. (At least I think so)

What I want is to show an undefined amount of Fragments which can all show different categories of the same list. So if possible I want to load the list only once and I want to reuse the Fragment code for every fragment since I don't want to restrict the max amount of categories.

My idea was to use the ApplistAdapter to filter the unwanted apps for every category but I really don't know. 
Help is really really appreciated since I have no idea how to go along.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `MyService.setItems(items);` a static method?

Comment: Also is `applistAdapter` the `Adapter` for your `ViewPager`? Updating the `Fragments` like this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I would change how this works all together. A few suggestions of the top of my head:

- Download the data in the `Service` instead of the `Activity` and
  persist it somewhere for example in a database.
- You can use an `Intent` to tell the `Service` what you want to download and when to do it.
- You can also use an `IntentService` instead of a `Service`.
  `IntentServices` already handle each `Intent` in a separate worker
  thread so you don't need an `AsyncTask` or anything like that in the
  `IntentService` to perform the downloading.
- Each `Fragment` should load the data from the database in `onResume()`. You
  can use local broadcasts to inform the `Fragments` when the data
  changed while they are being displayed.

If you don't give us more information it will be difficult to give you very specific advice.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please reread my question since I made it from scratch to provide more information. Your answer does unfortunately not help me. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Well my answer stays pretty much the same. Only that I can guarantee you that `return new ApplistFragment();` creates a new instance of a `Fragment`. Your question is way too broad. I can't provide a reasonable answer here. And I don't know if you just started a variable name with an uppercase letter or if this is a static method: `AppDrawerService.getApps()` but if it is a static method than I can tell you that this will just cause problems. Don't pass data statically between `Services` and `Activities`. To summarize: Try to narrow down your question on one specific problem.